# changing cart total price value asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, cart

I have a project for shop that there is a problem in the cart.

When someone adds a new order into the cart, I would like it to change the total price in database; however, I am running into some calculation issues.

this is the code in Controller

```
public IActionResult AddToCart(int itemId)
{
    var product = _context.Products.Include(p => p.Item).SingleOrDefault(p => p.ItemId == itemId);
    if (product != null)
    {

        int userId = int.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToString());
        var order = _context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserId == userId && !o.IsFinaly);

        if (order != null)
        {
            decimal orderTotal = order.TotalPrice;
            var orderDetail =
                _context.OrderDetails.FirstOrDefault(d =>
                    d.OrderId == order.OrderId && d.ProductId == product.Id);
            if (orderDetail != null)
            {
                orderDetail.Count += 1;
                foreach (var item in order.OrderDetails)
                {
                    orderTotal += item.Price * item.Count;
                }

                _context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                // If the order detail doesnt exist before
                _context.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail()
                {
                    OrderId = order.OrderId,
                    ProductId = product.Id,
                    Price = product.Item.Price,
                    Count = 1
                });
                foreach (var item in order.OrderDetails)
                {
                    orderTotal += item.Price * item.Count;
                }

                _context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            order = new Order()
            {
                IsFinaly = false,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = userId
            };
            _context.Orders.Add(order);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            _context.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail()
            {
                OrderId = order.OrderId,
                ProductId = product.Id,
                Price = product.Item.Price,
                Count = 1
            });
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ShowCart");
}
```

Comment: I would advice to move the business logic outside the controller. Create some unit tests to ensure it works and then call the logic from the controller.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify - what does `I am running into some calculation issues` mean?

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing your `orderTotal`-variable from the database and afterwards update an variable with the prices of your order - doing nothing with the variable except for calculating it. This does not change your database as it's a call by value for the simple type of `order.TotalPrice`. I think you want to *first* calculate the sum of the prices in the order and *afterwards* set it in your database:

```
public IActionResult AddToCart(int itemId)
{
    var product = _context.Products.Include(p => p.Item).SingleOrDefault(p => p.ItemId == itemId);
    if (product != null)
    {

        int userId = int.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToString());
        var order = _context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserId == userId && !o.IsFinaly);
        if (order != null)
        {
            var orderDetail =
                _context.OrderDetails.FirstOrDefault(d =>
                    d.OrderId == order.OrderId && d.ProductId == product.Id);
            if (orderDetail != null)
            {
                orderDetail.Count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // If the order detail doesnt exist before
                _context.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail()
                {
                    OrderId = order.OrderId,
                    ProductId = product.Id,
                    Price = product.Item.Price,
                    Count = 1
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            order = new Order()
            {
                IsFinaly = false,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = userId
            };
            _context.Orders.Add(order);
            _context.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail()
            {
                OrderId = order.OrderId,
                ProductId = product.Id,
                Price = product.Item.Price,
                Count = 1
            });
        }
       decimal orderTotal = 0;
       foreach (var item in order.OrderDetails)
       {
         orderTotal += item.Price * item.Count;
       }
       order.TotalPrice = orderTotal;
       _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ShowCart");
}
```

I also changed:
You do not need to call `SaveChanges()` multiple times or set the EntityState if you do not get the entity using `NoTracking()`. It is set automatically.

Your code might need some more refactoring as it is quite redundant and it's no good style to have this much code in your controller, but the changes above should solve your functional issues.

Comment: As already said in my first comment, 'it doesn't work' is not enough detail. Please use a debugger and step through, inspect your objects and see what's wrong.